# Ajax рендеринг партиала по завершению background job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

По сабмиту пользовательских данных запускается Sidekiq worker, который через некоторое время делает апдейт БД результатом запроса к API стороннего сайта.
Сейчас пользователь должен обновить страницу, чтобы увидеть результат. Это не гуд!

Подскажите, как обновить данные в конкретной строке таблицы по завершению работы workera? А еще лучше, как сделать прогресс индикатор выполнения этого задания, а уж по окончанию отрендерить результат.

Пробовал с Sidekiq-status, что-то не получается. Как вариант - запускать по сабмиту ajax запрос с периодичностью 3-5 сек до момента появления нужной записи в БД, но как реализовать это, я, к сожалению, не знаю.

Использование очереди необходимо дабы не превысить число запросов к API, поскольку в бэкграунде работает еще одна апдейт-очередь с более низким приоритетом, чем пользовательский запрос. Да и пользовательских запросов может быть больше одного в один момент времени.

Comment: Это можно сделать с помощью websocket. По завершению работы воркера отправлять сообщение на клиент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `Sidekiq-status`

Собственно, алгоритм таков:

1. По сабмиту отправляете ajax запрос на запуск воркера к заранее подготовленному REST API, к примеру, по адресу `POST /jobs/myjobs`

   ```
   def create
     render json: {job_id: MyJob.perform_async(params['Ваши входные данные'])}
   end
   ```
2. Полученный `job_id` используйте при периодических запросах к заранее подготовленному REST API, к примеру, по адресу `GET /jobs/myjobs/:job_id`
3. Примерный экшн show этого API:

   ```
   def show
     if Sidekiq::Status::complete? params[:job_id]
       return render json: ##хеш с результатами запроса к внешему API##
     end
     render json: Sidekiq::Status::get_all(params[:job_id])
   end
   ```
4. При необходимости отображать прогресс выполнения задачи, можно расширить этот экшн, используя методы

   ```
    Sidekiq::Status::at      job_id      #=> текущее значение счетчика
    Sidekiq::Status::total   job_id      #=> общее количество итераций
    Sidekiq::Status::message job_id      #=> сообщение, которое задается в perform
    Sidekiq::Status::pct_complete job_id #=> прогресс в процентах.
   ```

   для трекинга прогресса, необходимо так же расширить `perform` метод вашего воркера. Нужно задать общее количество итераций, используя метод `total` и, при необходимости, сообщения, используя метод `at`

Comment: буду пробовать. спасибо.